# Is there a real problem to which $1$ radian is the answer?

Tags: probability, geometry

I can't recall if I've ever seen any problem related to angles, in math or engineering books, that would result in an answer like $$\alpha=1 \ \ \text{radian}.$$ The answers to such questions, I recall, have sounded always like $$\alpha=\frac{n}{m}\pi \ \ \text{radians},$$ ($n$ and $m$ being integers.)

Now, apart from tasks like: divide the circumference of the unit circle by $2\pi$, can anyone recall a real problem to which $1$ radian was the answer?

I thought up a natural looking problem the answer to which turned out to be $1$ radian. I would share my finding with the community upon request.

Comment: Find a slice of pie such that the three sides (one of which is curved) are of equal length.

Comment: @vadim123: Had you seen this problem before? Or you just made it up right now to tease me. Your problem is simply the definition of the radian, put in an interesting way, though.

Comment: I've never seen an exercise where the answer was $17636748899001199$. Does this mean something? `;-)`

Comment: No, sorry. But it is nice of you to react. To defend myself: 1 is more interesting a number than 17633674889001199 is. ; (

Comment: By what angle does your bike wheel turn when you move forward a distance equal to the wheel’s radius?

Comment: Another interesting way to define one radian.

Comment: This seems like a pointless question to me. Why is a radian special?

Comment: This is subjective. To me 1 radian is interesting exactly because I haven't seen it appear as an answer to a real question, apart from different reformulations of the definition -- as seen twice above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case study

My question, to which the answer is $1$ radian, is a humble modification of Bertrand's paradoxical question related to randomly chosen chords of a circle.

Here is the secret question:

What is the impact angle of an average meteor path in a two dimensional world where meteors come randomly from any direction? (We consider only those meteors that hit our planet.)

(The angle $\alpha$, as shown below, is, by definition, the smaller angle between the meteor path and the tangent to the circle at the impact point. The randomness of the meteor path is hardly defined by ordering a random chord, however, a cord defines a path.)

Among the possibilities offered by text books as "probability distributions" of the random chord I liked the best the one that went like this: Fix a radius and use a random variable $X$ uniformly distributed over that radius. $X$ uniquely defines a chord, therefore a meteor path; just erect a perpendicular to the selected radius at $X$. This definition seemed to me to be the best model for a real physical experiment.Then I did the experiment. I drew circles of equal radius (4 cm) on the floor, climbed up to my desk and dropped spinning rulers onto the circles. My poor sister had to measure the randomly selected chords. It worked! After $3\ 000$ measurements we got $\pi$ to two digits as the average of the length of the chords (of the circles of $4$ cm's) So there is something to the definition given above. I did not repeat the ruler dropping experiment when I wanted to calculate the average angle of the average path of a two dimensional meteor.

[image]

I just did my calculation based on the fruitful model tested above. Guess what the result was? It was $1$ radian.

What do you think about the average angle of a meteor hitting a sphere?

Comment: I think the average angle comes out to $\int_0^1\arccos t\,dt$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Yes. And that integral equals 1. To me this result seemed to be interesting. Surprisingly a.e. found this question uninteresting, pointless, etc. I am honestly curious to learn why.